# create DockPanel inside a particular div element of UIBinder

Tags: gwt

Is it possible to add Panel to html elements in GWT?

I have checked and it does not contain wrap or setElement methods. I have also tried to check the source code and it does not have a constructor with Element as input. The constructor does call getTable() method which returns a table element, but I don't know where and how to set it.

Any ideas?

=============== EDIT ==================

By looking at the source code, it seems that this is not possible to do. DockPanel inherits from cellPanel and here is what is does in constructor.

```
  /**
   * Creates an empty dock panel.
   */
  public DockPanel() {
    DOM.setElementPropertyInt(getTable(), "cellSpacing", 0);
    DOM.setElementPropertyInt(getTable(), "cellPadding", 0);
  }

 public CellPanel() {
    table = DOM.createTable();
    body = DOM.createTBody();
    DOM.appendChild(table, body);
    setElement(table);
  }



  /**
   * Creates an empty dock panel.
   *
   * @param unit the unit to be used for layout
   */
  public DockLayoutPanel(Unit unit) {
    this.unit = unit;

    setElement(Document.get().createDivElement());
    layout = new Layout(getElement()); // private
    layoutCmd = new DockAnimateCommand(layout); // private
  }
```

==================== EDIT 2 ===========================

Given:

HTML

```
<html>
<body>
   <table id="dockLayoutPanel">
   </table>
</body>
</html>
```

JAVA/Js

```
   TableElement tEle = DOM.getElementById("dockLayoutPanel");
   DockPanel panel = new DockPanel(tEle);
   // and then use the panel as usual.
```

Comment: I am sorry to say, that I didn't get you. Are you trying to say, you want to add some gwt elements (Widgets) to a particular div in the HTML page? Is that what you are asking?
If not please tell exactly what you want, what you are expecting as out put.

Comment: @Path please add the source code your are trying to use and doesn't work. Adding gwt source code, which everybody can lookup, isn't going to be helpful. In general if you want to get a good answer write a question that best describes your problem, and focus less on the solutions your tried, what you think is wrong or causes the problem.

Comment: Yes looking back at the question, it is ambiguous. Sorry about that. What I want to do is, if you are given a <div id="abc"></div> element & now, in Java code I want to do, new DockPanel(Dom.getElementById("abc)) & it will create the DockPanel inside that element.  The source code that I quoted basically shows that this is not possible even if I extend the class. The whole framework is written to create elements on adhoc basis and attach them to DOM instead of being able to specify it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for how to add gwt widgets to particular html element, then here is the example for that.

Let us consider you want to add a `AbsolutePanel` to HTML div, with id ***myPanel***:
then you can achieve it by implementing like this:

```
AbsolutePanel aPanel = new AbsolutePAnel();
Rootpanel.get("myPanel").add(aPanel);
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: a better way is to just use HTMLPanel and wrap the element around a div tag. You can declare GWT elements inside div element in an HTML panel.